# Explanation on ContentAlignment enum values

Tags: c#, .net, enums

System.Drawing.ContentAlignment enum looks like this:

```
namespace System.Drawing
{
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies alignment of content on the drawing surface.
    [Editor("System.Drawing.Design.ContentAlignmentEditor, System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public enum ContentAlignment
    {
        TopLeft = 1,
        TopCenter = 2,
        TopRight = 4,
        MiddleLeft = 16,
        MiddleCenter = 32,
        MiddleRight = 64,
        BottomLeft = 256,
        BottomCenter = 512,
        BottomRight = 1024,
    }
}
```

Why are the values defined in kind of flag-style? Why are 8 and 128 missing?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps to make the `ContentAlignment` enum participate in bitwise operations.

> But why it isn't decorated with `FlagsAttribute`?

Because it isn't intented to be used as a bitwise flag by the client so they didn't decorate the enum with FlagsAttribute.

You can refer the .net framework source to see how they nicely use `ContentAlignment` with bitwise operations.

[ControlPaint.TranslateAlignment](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ControlPaint.cs,f8cb6cefbdd6deb1,references) make use of it and you can see the declarations with Bitwise OR in the [top of the class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ControlPaint.cs,bcc59f03901da718,references)

```
private static readonly ContentAlignment anyRight  = ContentAlignment.TopRight | ContentAlignment.MiddleRight | ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
private static readonly ContentAlignment anyBottom = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft | ContentAlignment.BottomCenter | ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
private static readonly ContentAlignment anyCenter = ContentAlignment.TopCenter | ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter | ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
private static readonly ContentAlignment anyMiddle = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft | ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter | ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

That should answer "why values defined in kind of flag-style".

> Why are 8 and 128 missing?

I have no idea with that. If someone have, a comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I saw a suggested edit from an anonymous user that tried to explain why 8 and 128 are missing. It was rejected because it was edited into the existing answer.

I think it is just speculation and not a definite answer, but it sounds plausible, so here it is (quoted from Sriram Sakthivel's answer):

> > Why are 8 and 128 missing?
>
> I have no idea with that. If someone have, a comment will be appreciated.

Let's take the bits then:

0000 0000 0000 0000

The reason there is no 8, 128, or anything above 1024 is the following:
For the first 3(TopLeft, TopCenter and TopRight) take the first 4 bits:

```
TopLeft = 1 (0001)
TopCenter = 2 (0010)
TopRight = 4 (0100)
```

Then second 3 (MiddleLeft, MiddleCenter and MiddleRight)

```
MiddleLeft = 16 (0001[0000])
MiddleCenter = 32 (0010[0000])
MiddleRight = 64 (0100[0000])
```

Then Last 3 (BottomLeft, BottomCenter and BottomRight)

```
BottomLeft = 256 (0001[00000000])
BottomCenter = 512 (0010[00000000])
BottomRight = 1024 (0100[00000000])
```

This makes it easy to use bitwise operations not only vertical but also horizontal.

Comment: Don't worry if your material is based on another answer, a comment, or a suggested edit. As long as you declare it, and offer something new in your answer, you are very welcome to take credit for the new answer. All material is Creative Commons licensed here, so it belongs to everyone.